# MySql - calculate time difference for multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table with manufacturing assembly data, including timestamps. I'm trying to determine the average interval in minutes between 'job' starts.

My query that returns the id and time looks like:

```
select job_id, job_started from JobTable where job_started >= '2016-07-01' and job_started <= '2016-07-31';
```

I'm looking for output that would be the difference in time between each row:

15
18
21
14
13

Comment: I'd recommend using a programming language to iterate over the rows. Not sure SQL has what you're asking for, and chances are not every DBMS will.

Comment: You don't need all intervals to get the average. You just need the time of the first job, the time of the last job and the number of all jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Get average interval in seconds:

```sql
select (to_seconds(max(job_started)) - to_seconds(min(job_started))) / (count(*) - 1) as average_interval_seconds
from JobTable
where date(job_started) >= '2016-07-01'
  and date(job_started) <= '2016-07-31'
;
```

Get all intervals in seconds:

```sql
select to_seconds((
  select t2.job_started
  from JobTable t2
  where t2.job_started > t1.job_started
    and date(t2.job_started) <= '2016-07-31'
  limit 1
)) - to_seconds(t1.job_started) as interval_seconds
from JobTable t1
where date(t1.job_started) >= '2016-07-01'
  and date(t1.job_started) <= '2016-07-31'
  and t1.job_started <> (
    select job_started
    from JobTable
    where date(job_started) <= '2016-07-31'
    order by job_started desc
    limit 1
  )
;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f8dc3/2