# Count total time difference (datediff) between dates

Tags: mysql

Looking for a way how to calculate the **total** "usage" times between two dates.
The usage is defined by two entries: start and stop, for example:

```
1   start   2018-01-10 10:11:00
2   foo     2018-01-11 09:15:00
3   stop    2018-01-11 20:10:00
4   start   2018-01-13 10:11:00
5   foo     2018-01-13 09:15:00
6   foo     2018-01-14 01:10:00
7   stop    2018-01-14 13:10:00
8   start   2018-01-16 15:51:00
9   foo     2018-01-16 04:45:00
10  foo     2018-01-17 03:30:00
11  stop    2018-01-18 15:20:00
```

I'm looking for a mysql query to get total usage time between 2018-01-13 10:11:00 and 2018-01-18 15:20:00, so I expect to get:

```
datediff(
    4   start   2018-01-13 10:11:00
    7   stop    2018-01-14 13:10:00
)
+
datediff(
    8   start   2018-01-16 15:51:00
    11  stop    2018-01-18 15:20:00
)
```

Comment: Please take a look at the Asking section of the Help pages (https://stackoverflow.com/help). Please post the code you've already written and explain how it's not working and someone may be able to help you. Unfortunately SO isn't a resource to get others to write code for you, there are other websites out there for that kind of requirement.

Comment: no, please see the updated question, I want to count several start-stop sessions as shown in the example.

Comment: @scaisEdge, why to give wrong info? I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39155968/mysql-calculate-time-difference-for-multiple-rows

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution here: [MySql - calculate time difference for multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39155968/mysql-calculate-time-difference-for-multiple-rows)

```
select to_seconds((
  select t2.job_started
  from JobTable t2
  where t2.job_started > t1.job_started
    and date(t2.job_started) <= '2016-07-31'
  limit 1
)) - to_seconds(t1.job_started) as interval_seconds
from JobTable t1
where date(t1.job_started) >= '2016-07-01'
  and date(t1.job_started) <= '2016-07-31'
  and t1.job_started <> (
    select job_started
    from JobTable
    where date(job_started) <= '2016-07-31'
    order by job_started desc
    limit 1
  )
;
```

Thanks all who said it's not possible and downvoted the question, you're really helping!

Comment: If you found the answer in another SO question, then pls mark your question as a duplicate pointing to the other question, do not answer yourself! Also, if you found that question and answer useful, then you should upvote them.

Comment: @Shadow All you care is to get some more points and not to help people. You miss the whole point of this resource..

Comment: can't follow you. How would any of this get me any points - if I were only interested in that?